# what permissions are required to allow users to upload files?

Tags: php, http, authentication, iis, permissions

We migrated our website from IIS 6 to IIS 8 and switched to 2012 windows server!

Users used to be able to upload images to the site and store them on the 2012 windows server.

This doesn't work anymore, and I think it may be a permissions issue.

THe way users are authenticating is through a simple database look up.

Once they have access to the site, they have the ability to upload pictures. Please note this has nothing to do with windows authentication.

**What set of permissions is required on the server to allow anonymous users to upload files?**

Comment: Is the directory you are using writable for whichever user the webservers runs as?

Comment: i dont know how can itest this

Comment: By writing a file there with PHP.... Or inspect its permissions yourself.